# Div formatting: center text vertically

Tags: html, css

This code genereates a sequence of: block,text,block,text,block,text and it looks about right except that I can't get the text to vertically align in the center of the div so it looks like its aligned next to the center of the boxes vertically. Any advice?

```
    <div style="position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; text-align: right;">
    <span style="display: inline-block; width: 15px; height: 15px; background: #2880BB"></span>                                     
    <span style="display: inline-block">Created   </span>                                            
    <span style="display: inline-block; width: 15px; height: 15px; background: #7FC31B"></span>
    <span style="margin-left: 5px;">Won   </span>
    <span style="display: inline-block; width: 15px; height: 15px; background: #FD2A2F"></span>
    <span style="margin-left: 5px;">Lost </span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate solution:

```
<div style="position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; text-align: right;">
    <span style="border-left: 15px solid #2880BB; padding-left: 5px;">Created</span>                                            

    <span style="border-left: 15px solid #7FC31B; margin-left: 5px; padding-left: 5px">Won</span>

    <span style="border-left: 15px solid #FD2A2F; margin-left: 5px; padding-left: 5px">Lost</span>
</div>​
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/w2wVc/1/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of height, you can use `line-height` to center text vertically. Check out this code:

#### HTML:

```
<div class="vertical">
    Hello
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.vertical {line-height: 50px; border: 1px solid #f00;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rv8pq/

Comment: Line height doesn't work, i tried that before posting. Thanks though!

Comment: The fiddle worked right? I tried it in jsFiddle. Check out the link... :)

Comment: Create a fiddle and I will try to correct the code. BTW, which browser and version?

Answer (score 0):

I've used position:relative and top:2px in your css. Change top pixel value as requirement.

```
<div style="position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; text-align: right;">
<span style="display: inline-block; position:relative; top:2px; width: 15px; height: 15px; background: #2880BB"></span>                                     
<span style="display: inline-block">Created   </span>                                            
<span style="display: inline-block; position:relative; top:2px; width: 15px; height: 15px; background: #7FC31B"></span>
<span style="margin-left: 5px;">Won   </span>
<span style="display: inline-block; position:relative; top:2px; width: 15px; height: 15px; background: #FD2A2F"></span>
<span style="margin-left: 5px;">Lost </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using a `-ve` margin to text. ***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/JYfdm/)*** is a live demo.

Answer (score 0):

my suggest is to put every `<span>` and its box in one `div` then clear right of every `div`

```
clear: right
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this a number of times with CSS and never had any luck (with good cross browser support).  I was able to get it working with some Jquery.

http://jsfiddle.net/EebmV/1/

Of you could go old school and use a table.  Table cells have always working for vertical alignment.

UPDATE:

Re-saved with the Jquery library referenced correctly.

Comment: Set the JavaScript library to jQuery, otherwise this fiddle won't work since it was saved with Mootools.

Answer (score 0):

I set the div as `display:table` and the spans as `display:table-cell`, so now you can set `vertical-align` like in table mode.

http://jsfiddle.net/w2wVc/10/